# Code Golf: Playing Cubes

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

### The challenge

The shortest code by character count, that will output playing bricks tower series according to user input.

The input will be a series of numbers (positive, negative and zero) that represents the height of the current cube tower following their index. A height of 0 means no tower and is spaced.

A cube tower is composed of stacked cubes. If the input number on the current index is positive, the cubes go up, if the input number is negative, the cubes go down. A single cube is drawn using the 4 following lines:

```
   __
 /__ /|
|   | |
|___|/
```

Cubes are 3D - this means they hide each other when two towers are placed next to each other, generating fake perspective.

All input can be assumed to be valid and without errors - Each number is separated with a white space on a single line, with at least one number.

### Test cases

```
Input:
    2 -3 -2 1 2 -1
Output:
       __              __
     /__ /|          /__ /|
    |   | |        _|   | |
    |___|/|      /__|___|/|
    |   | |__  _|   |   | |__
    |___|/__ /__|___|___|/__ /|
        |   |   | |     |   | |
        |___|___|/|     |___|/
        |   |   | |
        |___|___|/
        |   | |
        |___|/
```

---

```
Input:
    1 2 3 4 -2 4 3 2 1
Output:
                   __      __ 
                 /__ /|  /__ /|
               _|   | | |   | |__
             /__|___|/| |___|/__ /|
           _|   |   | | |   |   | |__
         /__|___|___|/| |___|___|/__ /|
       _|   |   |   | | |   |   |   | |__
     /__|___|___|___|/| |___|___|___|/__ /|
    |   |   |   |   | |_|   |   |   |   | |
    |___|___|___|___|/__|___|___|___|___|/
                    |   | |
                    |___|/|
                    |   | |
                    |___|/
```

---

```
Input:
    1 3 3 7 0 -2 -2
Output:
                   __
                 /__ /|
                |   | |
                |___|/| 
                |   | | 
                |___|/| 
                |   | | 
                |___|/| 
           __  _|   | | 
         /__ /__|___|/| 
        |   |   |   | | 
        |___|___|___|/| 
       _|   |   |   | | 
     /__|___|___|___|/| 
    |   |   |   |   | |    __  __
    |___|___|___|___|/   /__ /__ /|
                        |   |   | |
                        |___|___|/|
                        |   |   | |
                        |___|___|/
```

Code count includes input/output (i.e full program).

Comment: The -3 cube seemed to have lost during formatting. I am sorry for that. My draft clearly has this one. Thanks to LFSR for fixing :)

Comment: So... very... tempted... to add an example for 1 3 7 3 3

Comment: I've noticed a few more tiny space-related issues on the spec. Apparently SO doesn't like ASCII art :(

Comment: @Lira: use a <pre> block

Comment: I also forgot to mention - to all of my weekly code golf fans: Next week will be a **special Halloween edition** code-golf!

Comment: Is this challenge to hard? why are there no answers?

Comment: @LiraNuna, I don't believe it's hard, just too elaborate.  The whole negative thing adds a lot of code (for my solutions at least).  I don't want to optimize a 600-character solution, really.

Comment: Aww, put the negative cubes back!

Comment: Negative cubes are back. Though bring answers so it won't look dull!

Comment: I think your 0 example is a space off.

Comment: @Chris: Thank you! Another SO formatting issue...

Comment: @strager You have a 600 char solution to optimize? Lucky bastard. I'm starting at about 1400.

Comment: @mobrule, Surely not in perl??

Comment: @gnibbler - Maybe mobrule applies good coding practices and is currently trying to shorten `codeGolfCubingFunction` before applying the name-shortening. :P

Comment: @UK Jon Skeet is busy doing something else probably. ;-)

Comment: @mobrule, i see you managed to shave off 1214 bytes :p

Comment: I'm not gonna enter this one.  Too stringy for a C lover.

Comment: @strager, I thought you must be working on the golfscript

Comment: @gnibbler, This is beyond my Golfscript ability.  However, I have been convinced to work on a solution and will post it soon.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Perl 157 characters

This entry was inspired by gnibbler's Ruby entry, including the part about embedding the cube in the code. Also thanks to Kinopiko for schooling me on the 4 arg version of `substr`.

```
@O=($/.$"x99)x99;map{for$n(0..$_-1,$_..-1){map{substr$O[50-2*$n+$_],$W+4/$_,6,
(_,"__"
,"/__ /|",
"|   | |",
"|___|/")[$_]}1..4}$W+=4}@ARGV;print grep/\S/,@O
```

Explanation:

Line 1: Choose where cubes go
Lines 2-5: Put cubes where cubes go, print

Comment: `map{substr$O[-2*$n-$_],$W+$_*$_/3,(6,7,6,2)[$_],("|___|/","|   | |","/__ /|","__")[$_]}0..3}` gets you two more.
`/\S/&&print for@O[-49..49]` gets you one more.

Comment: `map{substr$O[-2*$n-$_],$W+($f=$_*$_)/3,6+$_-$f,("|___|/","|   | |","/__ /|","__")[$_]}0..3}`

Comment: Have you seen the C entry? :p

Comment: @Robert P: The C version is just a translation of this algorithm into C.

Comment: My ruby was based on my Python, so we have Python => Ruby => Perl => C :)

Comment: Grats for winning this week.  You're in for a scare this weekend though.  ;P

Answer (score 39):

## Ruby - 233

mutable strings ;)  No arbitrary "99" limits. pfft :p
Had to lose the picture of the cube in the source though

```
S=gets.split.map{|x|x.to_i}<<0
S.max.downto(S.min){|y|e=" ";q=e*3;r=e*3
S.map{|x|a=0,x;if(w=a.min)<=y&&x!=0&&y<z=a.max
r[-3,4]="|   | |";q[-3,4]="|___|/"+(y>w ?"|":e)else(z=z!=y)?q+=e*4:q[-2,4]="/__ /|"
r+=z ?e*4:"__  "end}
puts r,q}
```

## Ruby - 243

Delete the extra space I put in there to get the nice picture of the cube

```
S=gets.split.map{|x|x.to_i}<<0
S.max.downto(S.min){|y|e=" ";q=e*3;r=e*3
S.map{|x|a=0,x;if(w=a.min)<=y&&x!=0&&y<=z=a.max
if z==y;r+="__  "
 q[-2,3]="/__ /|"else
r[-3,4]="|   | |"
q[-3,4]="|___|/"+(y>w ?e:"|")end
else r+=e*4;q+=e*4 end}
puts r,q}
```

```
$ echo 1 3 7 3 3 |ruby pc.rb
           __              
         /__ /|            
        |   | |            
        |___|/|            
        |   | |            
        |___|/|            
        |   | |            
        |___|/|            
       _|   | |__  __      
     /__|___|/__ /__ /|    
    |   |   |   |   | |    
    |___|___|___|___|/|    
   _|   |   |   |   | |    
 /__|___|___|___|___|/|    
|   |   |   |   |   | |    
|___|___|___|___|___|/
```

Comment: I voted for the answer with 253 chars. It looks amazing with the actual cube in the solution.

Comment: OFFENSIVE! OFFENSIVE! OFFENSIVE! j/k.

Comment: With three more strokes and a co-location facility, I could change that "99" limit to "9E9"  ;-)

Answer (score 6):

### Python - 249

The second for loop is indented with tab

```
S=map(int,raw_input().split())+[0]
for y in range(max(S),min(S)-1,-1):
 q=r=e=" "*4
 for x in S:
    w=x*(x<0);z=x*(x>0)
    if w<=y<z:r=r[:-3]+"|   | |";q=q[:-3]+"|___|/"+" |"[y>w]
    elif(y==z)*x:q=q[:-2]+"/__ /|";r+="__  "
    else:q+=e;r+=e
 print r+"\n"+q
```

### Python - 393

```
S=map(int,raw_input().split())+[0]
for Y in range(max(S),min(S)-1,-1):
 Q=R="";B=s=t=" "*4;N=0
 for y in S:
  if(y>0)*(y==Y)+(Y==0)*(y<0):
   q="_  _";r=" /__";s="_   ";t=" /| "
   if(N<y>0)+(N==0):q="   _"
   if y<N>0:q="| |_";r="|/__"
  elif(y>Y>=0)+(y<=Y<0):q="|   ";r="|___";s="| | ";t="|/"+("| "[(y==Y<0)+(Y==0)])+" "
  else:q=s;r=t;s=t=B
  Q+=q;R+=r;N=y
 print Q.rstrip()+"\n"+R.rstrip()
```

Comment: The problem has changed, which will probably make your code a lot shorter.

Comment: doh! yeah, a lot shorter and about 1/10 as hard

Comment: Negative cubes don't display correctly. For example, just try `-1 -2`

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, <strike>261 258 250</strike> 242

```
c=[]
n=99
$F.map{|e|e=e.to_i
c<<(e<0?[e,-1]:[0,e-1])}
m=[]
x=0
c.map{|d|x+=4
k,l=d
(k+n..l+n).map{|y|y*=2
[[3,3,2,'__'],[2,1,6,'/__ /|'],[1,0,7,'|   | |'],[0,0,6,'|___|/']].map{|e|a,b,c,s=e
(m[y+a]||=' '*79)[x+b,c]=s}}}
puts m.compact.reverse
```

Run with `ruby -n -a v2.rb`

This entry is slightly overdesigned in that it can begin and end stacks at any level, not just at 0. There is no way to specify this in the "competition version", but if you replace the first 4 lines with `c=eval $_;n=99` then it drops to **203 bytes** and you can do: <

```
[[-3,3],[-3,-2],[2,3],[-3,-3],[-2,-1],[3,3],[2,2],[1,1],[0,0]]
```

```
           __      __          __                                                  
         /__ /|  /__ /|      /__ /|                                                
        |   | | |   | |     |   | |__                                              
        |___|/| |___|/|     |___|/__ /|                                            
        |   | | |   | |         |   | |__                                          
        |___|/| |___|/          |___|/__ /|                                        
        |   | |                     |   | |__                                      
        |___|/|                     |___|/__ /|                                    
        |   | |            __           |   | |                                    
        |___|/|          /__ /|         |___|/                                     
        |   | |__       |   | |                                                    
        |___|/__ /|     |___|/|                                                    
        |   |   | |    _|   | |                                                    
        |___|___|/|  /__|___|/                                                     
        |   |   | | |   | |                                                        
        |___|___|/  |___|/
```

Comment: Ohh, do me a favor, render [[3,3],[1,2],[0,3],[0,7],[0,3],[0,3]]

Comment: your version was actually my original idea, but it has a different approach which I'm reserving for another code golf challenge.

Comment: Put your output in a <pre> block to prevent highlighting.

Answer (score 6):

### Befunge-93 (too many characters)

Very unoptimized.  My first Befunge program.  =]

```
>~:88+`v6 >11p>:!|v                 g13$<       v            $<
 000090#8 + >      >68*31p  v >     1-:!|!:-1g14<p+g11g13+g12g 14<
   __  :* *      5 ^       < > 31pvvp16<>:41p1- 31g1+g :68*-!#^_ ^
 /__ /||\-6      >>1-:       |^8   < $<|       `g16 $<   <
|   | |>-*8 ^ ^ p11-2g11-1$  <    >31g   11g+:::51g` |   1
|___|/   8^0     >#-#<           v    ^<             >51p^
        <  <         |`0:       p 56 p34:p30:p26:p25:p22:p21:p20:*68<
^  v95:< 6^ *2:*  -10<           >21g4+21p 11
1  >*-   |            >     > 31g51gg,31g21g-3-!#v_v
1   >$ ^v<                 | ,+55-g16p15+1:g15   <
|!-*48 <~> ^                ^           p13+1g13   <
>   ^                      @
```

Comment: It might look better if you put it in a <pre> block, instead of a code block.

Comment: @Gilbert, Heh, true. =]  However, SO/Markdown doesn't like the < in my answer, so...

Comment: I was looking forward to seeing how you were going to beat my C solution with some kind of bizarre trick, and all I get is this? It looks like `more a.out`.

Comment: @Kinopiko, This isn't really my kind of problem.  I'm redoing the Befunge solution and will hopefully have it in before the deadline (as if it mattered).

Answer (score 5):

Haskell, 349 characters:

```
r=replicate
f=foldl
k=repeat
o n a s=r n a++s++k a
main=do{a<-getLine;let{n=map read$words a;u=f max 0 n;d=f min 0 n;i=r(2*(1+u-d))$r(4*length n+3)' '};putStr$unlines$f(\j(x,n)->f(\i y->[[if a=='x'then b else a|(a,b)<-zip m n]|(m,n)<-zip(o(2*(u-y))(k 'x')$map(o(4*x)'x')["xxx__xx","x/__ /|","|   | |","|___|/x"])i])j[1+min 0 n..max 0 n])i$zip[0..]n}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Golfscript - 154

Newlines are significant. If you fail to strip the trailing newline you will get an extra number printed at the bottom! There is a TAB between `-` and `0`

```
" "4*:s%{~}%0+: $):
;0=:g;{2,{:r;s {[
-   0
-]$(:b\(:t\;=!t!0t<1b>*2*+*[{s}[{"__  "}{-2<"/__ /|"}]r={-3<["|   | |""|___|/"["| "b!=]+]r=}]\=~+}%n}%
(:
g<!}do
```

**Golfscript - 163**

```
0`+" ":s%{~}%:A$):y;0=1-:g;{2,{:r;3s*A{[y- 0y-]$(:b\(:t\;=!:j;[{4s*}[{"__  "}{-2<"/__ /|"}]r={-3<["|   | |""|___|/"["| "b!=]+]r=}]0t=0t<1b>*2*+j*=~+}%n}%y(:y g>}do
```

**Golfscript - 165**

```
0`+" ":s%{~}%:A$):y;0=1-:g;{2,{:r;3s*A{[y- 0y-]$(:b\(:t\;=!:j;[
{4s*}.{"__  "
}{-2<"/__ /|"}
{-3<"|   | |"}
{-3<"|___|/"["| "b!=]+}]0t=2*0t<1b>*4*+r+j*=~+}%n}%y(:y g>}do
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, 287 characters

```
#define F(r)for(r=0;r<98;r++)
#define C(y,s)for(k=0;s[k];k++)b[49-i][w+k+y]=s[k];i++;
char k,i,j,w,t,b[98][99];main(c,v)char**v;{F(i)F(j)b[i][j]=32;
for(j=0;j<c;j++){i=2*atoi(v[j]);t=0;if(i>0)t=i,i=0;for(;i<t;i-=2){
C(0,"|___|/")C(0,"|   | |")C(1,"/__ /|")C(3,"__")}w+=4;}F(i)puts(b[i]);}
```

(this character count excludes two newlines)

This runs as a command line program, like

./cubes  1 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 2 -1 -10

You can try running it here: http://codepad.org/tu4HDqSy  (This version is altered because codepad.org doesn't allow command line arguments.)

A handy tip for un-golfing is to run it through `cpp` and then `indent`:

```
char                k        , i, j, w, t, b[98][99];
main(c, v)
    char          **v;
{
    for (i = 0; i < 98; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 98; j++)
            b[i][j] = 32;
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        i = 2 * atoi(v[j]);
        t = 0;
        if (i > 0)
            t = i, i = 0;
        for (; i < t; i -= 2) {
            for (k = 0; "|___|/"[k]; k++)
                b[49 - i][w + k + 0] = "|___|/"[k];
            i++;
            for (k = 0; "|   | |"[k]; k++)
                b[49 - i][w + k + 0] = "|   | |"[k];
            i++;
            for (k = 0; "/__ /|"[k]; k++)
                b[49 - i][w + k + 1] = "/__ /|"[k];
            i++;
            for (k = 0; "__"[k]; k++)
                b[49 - i][w + k + 3] = "__"[k];
            i++;
        } w += 4;
    } for (i = 0; i < 98; i++)
        puts(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Static-initialized elements are default zero, so `={}` is superfluous.  Using the pre-ANSI `main(c,v)char**v;{}` prototype shaves off two characters.  Pretty clever, though!  I wish I could find more to cut...

Comment: I get double spaced output on GCC 4.4.1.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the line wrap? If your terminal is less than 98 characters wide it wraps around. My gcc is gcc version 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD].

Comment: Ah, my terminal is a standard 80x24 in size. I think you need to specify it to whoever's testing :).

Comment: @Kinopiko: yes, I can resize my terminal, that's not the problem - the entry does not specify that it needs it, so I had no idea that this solutions outputs a static 98x98 buffer.

Comment: Since I'm not doing a C solution myself I'll help you with yours.  =]

Replace `if(i>0)t=i,i=0;for(;` with `for(i>0?t=i,i=0:0;`.  For your C macro, remove `""` from use and use `#s` instead of `s`.  Remove
`i=2*atoi(v[j])` and `char**v;` and replace `for(j=0;j<c;j++){t=0;` with `for(;scanf("%d",&i);t=0){i*=2;`  This will read the numbers from `stdin`.  You can now reuse any parameters to `main`.  (You will probably use `i` as a parameter to `main` because it has to be an `int`.)  Your init loop can be written as a single loop with a pointer (not sure if it helps in code size).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas though. I'll try using them next time.

Answer (score 3):

### Python (2.6), <strike>1092 905 623 501 478 345</strike> --> 318 characters

All comments welcome!

```
r=range;p="  __","/__ /|","|   | |","|___|/"
l=map(int,raw_input().split())+[0];d=max(l)
g=[[" "]*(len(l)+1)*4 for i in r(d-min(l)+1)*2]
for i,e in enumerate(l):
 for x,y in sorted([(i*4,(d-e+y-(0,1)[e<0])*2)for y in r(0,e,(1,-1)[e<0])])[::-1]:
  for i in r(4):g[y+i][(x,x+1)[i<2]:x+6]=p[i]
for k in g:print ''.join(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

**627 bytes of VB.NET 9** (without counting new lines)

```
Dim a As New List(Of Int32)
Dim b=InputBox("").Split(" ".ToCharArray)
For Each d In b
a.Add(Int32.Parse(d))
Next
Dim e=New String(){"|___|/","|   | |","/__ /|","__"}
Dim f=a.Min
Dim g=a.Max
Dim h=a.Count
Dim i As New List(Of String)
Dim j=(If(g>0,g,0)+If(f<0,-f,0))*2+1
For d=0To j
i.Add(Space(h*6))
Next
For d=f To g
If (d<>0) Then
For k=0To 3
Dim l=i(j)
Dim m=0
While m<h
If (d<0And a(m)<=d)Or(d>0And a(m)>=d) Then
Dim n=m*4+If(k>1,(k-2)*2+1,0)
l=l.Substring(0,n)&e(k)&l.Substring(n+e(k).Length)
i(j)=l
endif
m+=1
End While
j-=1
Next
j+=2
EndIf
Next
For Each d In i
Console.WriteLine(d)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 453 characters

```
s=io.read("*l")x={}for v in s:gmatch("-?%d+")do x[#x+1]=tonumber(v)end m=math
u=unpack s=string c={s.byte("   __   /__ /||###|#||___|/ ",1,28)}t=m.max(0,u(x))-1
b=m.min(0,u(x))l=#x*4+3 a={}for n=b,t do for p,v in ipairs(x)do y=n<0 and v<=n
or n>=0 and v>n for i=1,4 do e=(t-n)*2+i a[e]=a[e]or{}for j=1,7 do
d=c[(i-1)*7+j]f=(p-1)*4+j a[e][f]=y and d~=32 and d or a[e][f] or 32 end
end end end for i,v in ipairs(a)do print((s.char(u(v)):gsub("#"," ")))end
```

Answer (score 1):

**313 bytes of Ruby**

```
c=gets.split.map{|n|n.to_i}+[0];l=[" "*(c.length*5)]*((c.max-c.min)*2+2)
c.each_index{|i|h=c[i];h==0&&next
(h<0?(h...0):(0...h)).to_a.each{|b|y=c.max*2+1-b*2;x=i*4;s=(x+7)..-1
4.times{|a|l[y-a]=l[y-a][0,x+[0,0,1,3][a]]+['|___|/','|   | |','/__ /|','__'
][a]+(l[y-a][[(x+6)..-1,s,s,s][a]]||'')}}};l.each{|e|puts e}
```

(There is one newline that doesn't count, it's only there because otherwise there would be a very long line in there.)

I used the obvious method of making a 2D array of characters and pasting in the cubes one at a time, bottom to top and left to right.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP - <strike>447</strike> 398**

I Know it's not as short as the others here, but I'm happy with it ;)

```
<?$g=$argv;unset($g[0]);$c=array('|___|/',' '=>'|   | |','/__ 
/|',3=>'__');$x=max(max($g),0);$m=$i=min(min($g),0);$row=$y=0;
while($x>=$i){$n=$row++*2;foreach ($c as $w=>$p){
$L[]=str_pad('',count($g)*4," ");$t='';$y=0;foreach ($g as $h)
{if((($h>=$i&&$i>0)||($h<$i&&$i<=0)))$L[$n]=substr_replace($L[$n],$p,4*$y+$w,
strlen($p));$y++;}$n++;}$i++;}array_splice($L,$n);krsort($L);
print implode("\n",$L);?>
```

Input / Output

```
   C:\development\code-golf>php cubes1.php 1 2 1 -5 -5 4 3 3
                       __
                     /__ /|
                    |   | |__  __
                    |___|/__ /__ /|
       __           |   |   |   | |
     /__ /|         |___|___|___|/|
   _|   | |__       |   |   |   | |
 /__|___|/__ /|     |___|___|___|/|
|   |   |   | |__  _|   |   |   | |
|___|___|___|/__ /__|___|___|___|/
            |   |   | |
            |___|___|/|
            |   |   | |
            |___|___|/|
            |   |   | |
            |___|___|/|
            |   |   | |
            |___|___|/|
            |   |   | |
            |___|___|/
```

Comment: input is separated by spaces, not commas.