# Strange Variable Assignment in C

Tags: c, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737634/c-comma-operator)

I came across a line of code which I couldn't understand. I remember seeing something similar somewhere.

```
int x,y,z;
x=(y=2,z=2*y,z+4);
```

I know that the value assigned to x is 8. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Where did you come across this line of code?

Comment: @Oli: Probably on a website for "obfusctated C code" or "Here's why I love Java, because you can't do strange things like this C-code that no one can understand".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
 y = 2;      // y == 2
 z = 2 * y;  // z == 4
 x = z + 4;  // x == 8
```

The operands of the comma operator are evaluated from left to right and the result is the value of the right operand.

Comment: Is there a special name for this type of assignment ?

Comment: @AshRj yes, "dontdoit assignment"

Comment: Yes, there is a name for it "Rubbish!"

Comment: I ask because i have never seen this in any C books that i refer/use. Whats the problem in doing this ?

Comment: @AshRj: Because it is not a good practice to use it. That simply doesn't make it invalid. The problem is same as you faced. it is not readable!

Comment: @AlokSave Its not good practise because people dont know about it, or because there are some hidden dangers lurking behind it ?

Comment: It is a good idea NOT to use this, because like you, most people won't understand what it does [and it's clearly not logical or useful in any way]. Code should be easy to understand.

Comment: Because it is clever by half. In C it's "not so bad" i.e. merely confusing the first time you see it. But in C++ people (naturally) want to turn "not so bad" to "not so bad++" i.e. god-awful obfuscated code through the magic of operator overloading. Google "comma" and operator overloading. Still, that might just be considered a reason why C++ is to be avoided -- not necessarily the fault of the comma.

Comment: And if you think "Well, if it's hard to understand, no one will steal my code", then you have to consider that if it's actually worth protecting [that is, given the idea of WHAT you do in the first place, would it really be the code, or the idea, that is valuable], would someone put a lot of effort in taking your code, or just writing their own from scratch. Unreadable code would definitely not help if you ever came to sell your idea to a commercial entity.

Comment: @AshRj because there is no reason to do it and it obfuscates the code, do only one thing on each line. Or at least a small set or related operations, like `++i, ++j;`. Comma operator is useful sometimes, in `for` loops for example.

Comment: @effeffe: The key here is to not use assignment from a set of comma operator separated expressions, as it rarely does anything useful anyways. Sure, doing to increments, or `q = p, p = p->next` on a for-loop line is fine.

Comment: Quite a few reasons against using it.

Comment: @AshRj without any good reason to do it, even one reason against it it's enough to avoid it.

Comment: @Oli It was a question I found in a test, maybe that's why they used this odd assignment. Thank you all for the answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

the comma operator separates the previous values, and the last item in the comma is returned as the result, e.g.

```
a = b,c
```

assings the value of c to a. The parentheses here do essentially nothing, btw

So you have two assignments, then a statement, whose result is returned and assigned to x