# Unknown "for" statement (C)

Tags: c, for-loop

While browsing through foreign code I came across this:

```
      for(i = 0; i < len; i++,j)
```

Can anybody tell me what the "j" does here? I guess it's something simple, but I don't understand the meaning. "j" is declared as a uint16_t and initialized with 0.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Probably it's some left over from a previous version of the code. If you are in charge of the code or can commit changes, remove the `j`.

Comment: See here for the *comma operator*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737634/c-comma-operator

Comment: It's an evidence for a bad code review.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this was called the comma operator. @alk, would you want to post this as an answer (even though it's obviously and obvious one ;-) )?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the comma operator \`,\` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

Comment: @alk I think I tend to agree, though I am thinking still. OP did not know what happens when we simply put `j;` as a statement or whether it was his ignorance about the comma operator.

Comment: The canonical description of `for` is `for (init-expression ; condition-expression ; loop-expression)`. Merely stating `j` is not invalid (comma-operator or not), but it is only *evaluated* in the center `condition-expression`.

Comment: It was not knowing the comma operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is valid

```
for(i=0; i<len; i++,j++);
```

and is equivalent to

```
for(i=0; i<len; i++,j)
{
j++;
}
```

which is further equivalent to

```
//NOTE-there is no j after the i++;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
    j++;
    }
```

So there is no need to write j in your for(statement). The j written in your for(statement), has no function. So it can be omitted without effecting the program.

NOTE- the following code is valid and wont give any error but it is meaningless.

```
10;
```

Answer (score 1):

C allows one to initialize/update multiple variables in a for loop, separated by commas. For example: `for(i =0, j=0; i < 4; i++, j++)` This statement isn't updating anything, and is useless.

Comment: j is not same as j=j.

Comment: This statement would not do anything. It's not even doing 'j=j'. This code piece will be cut out during compilation.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would still try to update j. I edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It is redundant, to put it simply.

Answer (score 0):

This code is valid,It will not give any error.And you can skip j also.There is no use of this.