# How to take characters from an array and store them in a variable?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int agecalc;
    int nextyr;
    int birthday;
    int currentday;
    int agecalcu;
    int randomnumbers;

    birthday = 1987;
    currentday = 2016;
    nextyr = currentday + 1;
    agecalc = currentday - birthday;
    randomnumbers = 7890;

    char My[] = "Sayan Banerjee";

    printf("%s 's birthday is %.3d \n", My , agecalc);

    agecalcu = agecalc + 1;

/* alternatively I can use one int and change the variable stored in agecalc by stating that
agecalc = currentday - birthday +1; But I think that is just messy and disturbs a lot of code. declaring a new int is
better and less intrusive. this way when I may need to use agecalc again, i dont have to worry about the value stored in that
variable. */

    printf("%.5s will turn %.3d on %d.\n \a", My , agecalcu , nextyr);

    printf("The username for %s is %.6d \n", My , randomnumbers);
    // the thing here is that I cannot shorten a value stored in a value unless its in an array
    // but I can express it in other ways like 1 to 01.
    /* The thing is that I cannot store two %s in one argument/code. this freezes the code. better way would be to
    create another variable and then try to edit that.*/

    //this is an experiment to see whether I can take characters from an array and store it in a variable
    int user;


    My [0,1,2,3,4,5] = user;

    printf("%s is also %s", My , user );


   return 0;
}
```

The main question I have is in the last line. I am a newbie to coding and have just started learning. I was just playing around and noticed that if I put in two `%s` in the same argument the program kind of crashes. So, I was thinking if I can take certain characters in the array My and store them in a  variable and then print it?

Is it possible? or am I just looking at this in the wrong way?
Sorry for the messy post. 
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: also, the comments there, are just what I discovered tinkering around. I may be wrong in what I wrote, but I just posted the whole thing. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [page on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), that way your question won't be as "messy".  Also keep in mind that you can always [edit] your question.

Comment: By the way, if `x = y` assigns the value of `y` to `x`, does your `My ... = user` makes sense to you? (I don't have time for a full answer at the moment, sorry).

Comment: `My [0,1,2,3,4,5] = user` what do you expect this line of code to do?

Comment: @Zeta thanks for your answer. What I wanted to do was take the characters stored in the My array ( My[] = "Sayan Banerjee"; ) and take the "Sayan" part and store it in a variable. and then access it later with the ("%s is also %s \n", My, user) part of the code. Sorry. But I am not very expressive in this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`My [0,1,2,3,4,5] = user;`

This line is equivalent to saying

`My[5] = user;`

That's because of the [comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) operator

```
//this is an experiment to see whether I can take characters from an array and store it in a variable
```

You can. But what you are doing right now is assigning an un-assigned value to the `5th` element of the `My` array. `int val = My[5]` is perfectly fine to do not the other way round though.

The crash is happening because your code is trying to interpret an integer as a `null terminated string` because of `%s` format specifier that you gave

```
printf("%s is also %d", My , user ); // %d for integers
```

Your code in current state is in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) land.

To copy certain characters from an existing array into the target array you will need more than one variable. A single variable will just hold a single character.

```
char user[6];
user[5] = '\0'; // fill the last character as null to be a valid C string
user[0] = My[0];
user[1] = My[1];
user[<any other index you want>] = My[<The index you want>];
```

You can save yourself much energy, time and effort by simply using functions from [string.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/) which has bunch of utilities for string manipulation. Probably what you need for your current problem is [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)

As an orthogonal suggestion, compile your code with the highest warning level supported by your compiler. The compiler will shout out these issues at compile time.

For eg `gcc -Wall filename.c`

Comment: when i try using int val = My[5] then the output comes out as Sayanpbanerjee is also @.  And if I take your other idea then the output is Sayanpbanerjee is also 4200816. 
Now, I might be wrong but, aren't we able to save "strings or text" in an int variable? Then why is this giving me such a weird output?

Comment: BTW, English isn't my first language so I kind of trip up while explaining things. The original intent of the code was to take certain letters in the array and then put them into a variable and then try to run it in the code.

Comment: @SayanBanerjee updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: thanks for the help. I did look at the answer and while it made some sense, I don't think I have the knowledge to pull it off atm. So, I am going to try this again after attending a few more classes!

Comment: @SayanBanerjee While this is completely unrelated to the question, but I would suggest that instead of taking more classes try writing more code. I don't know your college/course but I do know that these things are best learned outside classroom.

Answer (score 0):

Following line does not do what you think:

this:

```
My [0,1,2,3,4,5] = user;
```

is actually the same thing as this:

```
My [5] = user;
```

Read about the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737634/c-comma-operator).

Anyway, you cannot store the whole `My`array in a single `int` variable.

---

Here you are using `%s` for printing `user` which is not a `char*` but an `int`

```
printf("%s is also %s", My , user );
```

This results in undefined behaviour, most likely a crash on modern systems.

---

As for your question it is a bit unclear, you maybe want this:

```
#include <string.h>
...
char user[20];
strcpy(user, My);

printf("%s is also %s", My , user);
```

which will print:

```
Sayan Banerjee is also Sayan Banerjee
```

Comment: First things first. Thanks for all the help! I knew a little about strcpy, I don't know Why I didn't use it myself. well the code works, and I can keep it to 15. So why did you specify 20? It's not what I wanted originally,and editing the byte size in user to anything below 15 doesn't give the result I am looking for.
What I am looking for is taking out certain characters from an array : maybe the B, N, J, R, S and put it in the variable. Is there any way to do that? Thanks again for all your patience!