# Can a function be defined after main()?

Tags: c, function, return, return-value

I have a code which looks like this and executes completely fine,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
int i = 3, j = 4, k, l ;
k = addmult ( i, j ) ;
l = addmult ( i, j ) ;
printf ( "\n%d %d", k, l ) ;
}
int addmult ( int ii, int jj )
{
int kk, ll ;
kk = ii + jj ;
ll = ii * jj ;
return ( kk, ll ) ;
}
```

My question is that can we define a function afterwards without defining function prototype at the top and how can a function return two values?

Comment: Your function does not return two values. You should read about what the comma operator does. Also, in C if you don't have a prototype there is an implicit one that assumes you return an int. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737634/c-comma-operator

Comment: One should declare or prototype all the functions in respective headers before using them. Compile with `-Wstrict-prototypes` compiler will warn you about missing declaration of `addmult()`. Compile code with all warnings flags for e.g `gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can we define a function afterwards without defining function prototype at the top

You can declare its proto in `main`. In your case, the function accepts `int`s and returns an `int`, so the default prototype (are they still alive in the Standard?) worked fine.

> how can a function return two values?

1. It can return a struct by-value:

   ```
   typedef struct { int first; int second; } int_pair;
   int_pair addmult(int x, int y) {
       return (int_pair){42, 314}; /* enough for the demo, lol (c) */
   }
   ```

   Or by-pointer:

   ```
   int_pair *addmult(int x, int y) {
       int_pair *retVal = malloc(sizeof(int_pair));
       return retVal->first = 42, retVal->second = 314, retVal;
   }
   int_pair *multadd(int x, int y) {
       static int_pair retVal{314, 42};
       return &retVal;
   }
   ```
2. It can return a fresh array on the heap:

   ```
   /* 1. It is user's responsibility to free the returned pointer. */
   int *addmult(int x, int y) {
       int *retVal = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
       return retVal[0] = 42, retVal[1] = 314, retVal;
   }
   ```
3. Finally, it can return an array without allocating the latter on heap:

   ```
   /* 1. It is user's responsibility to NEVER free the returned pointer. */
   int *addmult(int x, int y) {
       static int retVal[] = {42, 314};
       return retVal;
   }
   ```

   In this case, the returned array can be reused (rewritten) by consequent calls so you should make use of its contents as soon as possible.

Comment: 4) Since C99 you can return a compound literal: `return (int_pair){42, 314};`

Comment: This is basically 1. but thank you, I was hoping something like this is possible.

Comment: Yes, is basically 1), just for completness ... :)

Comment: "Default prototypes" are dead since C99.  They actually never were a thing, but a function would be implicitly declared (without a prototype) as returning type `int` if it was encountered in a call in C90.  But C99 stops that; every function (except `main()`) must be defined or declared before it is used.  It still doesn't have to be declared with a prototype, but it is strongly recommended that you should always use an explicit prototype.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Consequently, OP uses C90 (at most) so I was wondering.

Comment: @KeineLust For completeness, returning a pointer-to-struct should be noted. :)

Comment: Also the OP uses C90 at least; prototypes didn't exist in C before C90 (for all practical purposes).  So, the code as written conforms (more or less) to C90.  It doesn't do what's wanted, but that's a somewhat different problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Means is the code logically incorrect if asked to point out?

Comment: @bipll: I don't see any advantage to `return retVal->first = 42, retVal->second = 314, retVal;` compared with `retVal->first = 42; retVal->second = 314; return retVal;` (spread over 3 lines for readability).  Also, it is best not to declare any function prototypes inside another function — for all it is legal to do so.  The declaration should be at file scope.

Comment: @SahilSilare: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The `return(kk, ll);` does nothing useful in the code in the question (because that's a comma operator, so the first argument is evaluated for side effects — and there are none — and then the result is discarded).  Hence, the value of `kk` is ignored, so the calculation is unnecessary, and an optimizing compiler will remove it.