# UITableView tied to a NSArray

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` that derives its data from an `NSArray`.  In the same view as the `UITableView`, there is a `UIDatePicker`.  When the date in the `UIDatePicker` changes, then I need to update the `NSArray` that provides data to the the `UITableView` and reload the table.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to change the `NSArray` without crashing my app.  I think that the tableview is tied to the NSArray and if I try to release it then that's what causes the crash.

Here's the method that is called when the `UIDatePicker`'s date is changed:

```
- (IBAction)datesChanged {
    // Update the availableUnits NSArray
    if (availableUnits != nil) {
        [availableUnits release], availableUnits = nil;
    }
    availableUnits = [self availableUnitsForGivenTime];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Oh god why are you using the comma operator? *shudder*

Comment: @Jonathan, And what's wrong with it? Even my hero Marcus Zarra uses the comma operator. See recently: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/06/05/re-ordering-nsfetchedresultscontroller/

Comment: @Neal: Appeal to authority. Munging two logical operations into a single statement leads to harder-to-read code. In the case of `[x release], x = nil` it's not so bad but it encourages worse behaviour down the line. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSMutableArray insted NSArray and each time when you change date then first remove old date from Array.Declare NSMutable array as property and alloc it in ViewDidLoad.then.

```
- (IBAction)datesChanged {

    [self.availableUnits removeAllObjects];
    self.availableUnits = [[self availableUnitsForGivenTime] retain];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And release the array in dealloc

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not retaining `availableUnits` after releasing it. Try with

```
availableUnits = [[self availableUnitsForGivenTime] retain];
```