# How is the comma operator being used here?

Tags: c++, comma-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Comma Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator)
>   [Uses of C comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator)

I am not new to C++, but this is the first time I see the following code:

```
int a=0;
int b=(a=2,a+1);
```

That is C++ code. Can you tell me what is going on here? And how variable b gets value 3?

Comment: Don't write code like that its horrible to read.

Comment: That was the code I saw. And what do you mean by horrible to read? You mean not to use comma operator in that case or what?

Comment: @seeker - If we have to ask what the code does, it *is* horrible code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code is equivalent to this:

```
int a = 2 ; 
int b = a + 1 ;
```

First expression to the left of comma gets evaluated, then the one to its right. The result of the right most expression is stored in the variable to the left of `=` sign.

Look up the comma operator for more details.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: Are you sure? I think the code is equivalent to `int b = a = 2; int b = a + 1;` notice the subtle difference

Answer (score 3):

`(a = 2, a + 1);` return 3 because in general case operator (a, b) return b, and calculation in (a, b) started from right to left. So, in your case, `(a = 2, a + 1)` return `a + 1`, and  after operator `a = 2` was executed `a + 1` return 3.