# Output to file c++

Tags: c++

very simple program, not sure why it isn't working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{
ofstream myfile ("test.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()) 
{
    for(  int i = 1;  i < 65535;  i++  )

     {
     myfile << ( "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 %d udp </connection>\n", i );
     }
    myfile.close();
}
  return 0;
}
```

Basically it should print that sentence 65535 times, and then save it to a txt file. But the txt file just has a list of numbers from 1 to 65535, no words or formatting. Any ideas? Thanks for help.

Comment: The comma operator: Causing confusion since who knows when!

Comment: Read here how comma operator is used.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824378/how-is-the-comma-operator-being-used-here/12824426#12824426

Comment: Thanks it works now, however i made a mistake in that i can only have up to 64 numbers, and they need to be random between 10001 and 65535. Anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the output, just pipe your data into two `<<` operators, as such:

```
myfile << "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 %d udp </connection>\n" << i;
```

Note that interpolation does not work in that case, so if you want to put your `i` variable into the middle of the string, you have to either split it by hand:

```
myfile << "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 " << i << " udp </connection>\n"
```

Or apply some sort of other interpolation formatting before outputting it.

### The problem

The problem exists in your code because in C++, `(a, b)` (the comma operator) returns `b`. So, in your code it meant you just wrote `i` to a file.

Comment: does `<<` work like printf? cuz i believe he is using printf syntax

Comment: Nope, it of course doesn't. I've added a bit to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
myfile << ( "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 %d udp </connection>\n", i );
```

to

```
myfile << "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 " << i << " udp </connection>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
myfile << "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 %d udp </connection>\n" << i;
```

Basically, `myfile << (str , i)` means "*evaluate `(str , i)` and write the result of evaluation to ostream myfile*".

The result of `( "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 %d udp </connection>\n", i )` evaluation is equal to `i`

Take a look to comma operator description:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 0):

You are using printf syntax to write using ofstream. Others have explained why it doesnt work. To fix it do the following

```
myfile << "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160"<<i<<"udp </connection>\n";
```

or if you want to go C style

```
printf( "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 %d udp </connection>\n", i ); //fprintf to write to file
```

Comment: How he is supposed to use `fprintf` if he opened the `fstream`? I'd understand `sprintf` suggestion.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz sorry for not explaining better, C style would mean `fopen`/`fclose` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to "printf" and stream...

I think this is more like what you want:

```
myfile << "<connection> remote 208.211.39.160 " << i << " udp </connection>"<<std::endl;
```