# Comma as a separator and operator

Tags: c++, c

So I came across this question somewhere:

Case 1:

```
int a;
a = 1, 2, 3;
printf("%d", a);
```

Case 2:

```
 int a = 1, 2, 3;
 printf("%d", a);
```

The explanation says:

The second case gives error because comma is used as a separator, In first case `=` takes precedence over `,` so it is basically `(a=1), 2, 3`;

But I want to ask why does `=` not take precedence over `,` in Case 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the comma operator being used here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824378/how-is-the-comma-operator-being-used-here)

Comment: Are you sure the cases or explanations aren't backwards?

Comment: The question is incorrect. Case 1 is legal, Case 2 is a syntax error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
int a = 1, 2, 3;/* not a valid one */
```

is wrong because since `=` has higher priority, so it become `int a = 1` internally and there is no name for `2` and `3` thats why this statement is not valid and cause compile time error.

To avoid this you might want to use

```
int a = (1, 2, 3); /* evaluate all expression inside () from L->R and assign right most expression to a i.e a=3*/
```

And here

```
int a;
a = 1,2,3;
```

there are two operator `=` and `,` and see `man operator`. The assignment operator `=` has higher priority than `comma` operator. So it becomes `a=1`.

```
a = 1,2,3;
    | L--->R(coma operator associativity) 
    this got assigned to a
```

for e.g

```
int x = 10, y = 20,z;
z = 100,200,y=30,0; /* solve all expression form L to R, but finally it becomes z=100*/ 
printf("x = %d y = %d z = %d\n",x,y,z);/* x = 10, y = 30(not 20) z = 100 */
z = (100,200,y=30,0); /* solve all expression form L to R, but assign right most expression value to z*/
```

Answer (score 10):

It is not just a question of precedence, but rather a question of the language grammar: the `=` in both cases is not the same operator:

- in the declaration `int a = 1, 2, 3;`, the `=` token introduces an initializer which cannot be a comma expression. The `,` ends the initializer and the compiler issues an error because `2` is not a valid identifier for another variable.
- in the statement `a = 1, 2, 3;`, `a = 1, 2, 3` is an expression, parsed as `((a = 1), 2), 3` because `=` has higher precedence than `,`. `=` is the assignment operator whose right hand side is an expression, this assignment is the left operand of a comma operator `,` followed by a constant expression `2`, `a = 1, 2` itself the left operand of the final `,` operator whose right operand is `3`. The statement is equivalent to `((a = 1), 2), 3);`, which simplifies into `a = 1;`.

Comment: In particular, the `=` token introduces an *assignment-expression*, which is defined in C 2011 6.5.16, which can be any of the prior types of expression (*conditional-expression*, *logical-OR-expression*, and so on) but cannot be an *expression*, which comes later, in 6.5.17.

Comment: However, the statement that the right-hand side of an assignment expression can be a comma expression is incorrect. The right-hand side of an *assignment-expression* is an *assignment-expression*. In `a = 1, 2, 3;`, the text is parsed as `((a = 1), 2), 3;`. What is actually happening here is that `a = 1, 2, 3;` is a *statement*, in particular an *expression-statement*, in which `a = 1, 2, 3` is an *expression*, which can be “*expression*, *assignment-expression*”.

Answer (score 5):

Inside variable declarations (as case 1) comma are used to declare several variables, for example:

```
int a,b=2,c=b+1,d; //here only b and c were initialized
```

An statement in C/C++ could be a list of comma separated expressions (this is what happens in case 2):

```
a=b+1, c+=2, b++, d = a+b+c, 3, d; //these are expressions, remember one literal is an expression too!!!
```

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE :** comma (,) is a **compile time operator**,
from my side their is **Four cases** that you can come across :
**case 1**

```
int a = 1, 2, 3; // invalid case cause too many initializers
```

**case 2**

```
int a = (1, 2, 3); // valid case
/* You can expand this line as a :
   1;
   2;
   int a = 3;
*/
```

**case 3**

```
int a;
a = 1, 2, 3; // valid case
/* You can expand this line as a : 
   a = 1; // expression 1
   2;     // expression 2            
   3;     // expression 3
*/
```

**case 4**

```
int a;
a = ( 1, 2, 3);// valid case
/* You can expand this line as a :
   1;     // expression 1
   2;     // expression 2
   a = 3; // expression 3
*/
```

In above cases in place of 1, 2, 3 we can use any valid expression in C, explore more!!

Comment: "compile-time operator" is not a thing