# C++ comma operator confusion

Tags: c++

Similar question to:

[How is the comma operator being used here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824378/how-is-the-comma-operator-being-used-here)

```
BOOL bShowLoadingIcon = FALSE;
if (sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == 0 || sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == 16 || (bShowLoadingIcon = TRUE, sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == -1))
{
    bShowLoadingIcon = FALSE;
}
```

In the above code sample what values/range of sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 would cause bShowLoadingIcon to be set to TRUE. Is it possible it would be set to TRUE and also become true (overall if expression) thus also then being set back to FALSE?

I have no idea what `(bShowLoadingIcon = TRUE, sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == -1)` is actually doing.

Comment: What kind of code is this?

Comment: @HenriMenke You still need to set `bshowLoadingIcon` to `TRUE` if `sCurrentLevelId_5C3030` is neither 16, 0, nor -1.

Comment: What are `BOOL`, `TRUE` and `FALSE`?

Comment: BOOL is a nasty win32 type :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ only evaluates a boolean OR if it needs to. So if `sCurrentLevelId_5C30303` is `0` or `16`, the last statement never gets evaluated.

If `(bShowLoadingIcon = TRUE, sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == -1)` does get evaluated, it first sets `bShowLoadingIcon` to `TRUE` and then evaluates to the result of `sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == -1`. If that's true, then `bShowLoadingIcon` will just get set back to `FALSE`.

So in summary, `bShowLoadingIcon` is set to `FALSE`. Then if `sCurrentLevelId_5C3030` is neither `0` nor `16`, then `bShowLoadingIcon` is set to `TRUE`, only to be set back to false if `sCurrentLevelId_5C3030` is `-1`.

So, in even more summary, `bShowLoadingIcon` is set to `TRUE` if `sCurrentLevelId_5C3030` is neither `0` nor `16` and stays that way so long as `sCurrentLevelId_5C303030` is not `-1`.

It's equivalent to:

```
BOOL bShowLoadingIcon = (
    (sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 != 0) &&
    (sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 != 16) &&
    (sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 != -1)) ? TRUE : FALSE:
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
BOOL bShowLoadingIcon = (
    (sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == 0) ||
    (sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == 16) ||
    (sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == -1)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++, the comma operator (`statementX, statementY`) first executes `statementX`, and then `statementY`. The expression holds the value of the second statement.

In your code, `bShowLoadingIcon` is assigned the value `TRUE`, and then the value that C++ checks for in the if statement is whether `sCurrentLevelId_5C3030 == -1`.