# Can a variable be initialized with an istream on the same line it is declared?

Tags: c++, int, cin

Can the following two lines be condensed into one?

```
int foo;
std::cin >> foo;
```

Comment: Maybe `int old; std::cin >> old;`?

Comment: I re-titled this old and embarrassing question since it's been getting a lot of attention recently.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The smart-ass answer:

```
int old; std::cin >> old;
```

The horrible answer:

```
int old, dummy = (std::cin >> old, 0);
```

The proper answer: `old` has to be defined with a *declaration* before it can be passed to `operator>>` as an argument. The only way to get a function call within the declaration of a variable is to place it in the initialization expression as above. The accepted way to declare a variable and read input into it is as you have written:

```
int old;
std::cin >> old;
```

Comment: smart-ass answer, lol. thanks, that's informative

Comment: the `, 0` is redundant; - `istream` has implicit conversion to integer type

Answer (score 11):

You can... with

```
int old = (std::cin >> old, old);
```

but you really should not do this

Comment: Ah, good point! Clever.

Comment: @6502 why we shouldn't do what you say??

Comment: @Mohammasd • because if the `std::cin >> old` fails (i.e., returns false), then `old` is not initialized, and then reading `old` (the second part, after the comma operator) is undefined behavior.  And undefined behavior is bad.

Comment: With regards to undefined behavior, how is this example different from example a) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615656/2725810 that was highly up-voted?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: 1) unfortunately while there is some important correlation, the number of votes or the rep of the author doesn't mean an answer is correct... there's no justification for turning your brain off and just pasting from SO. 2) in the `str` example s/he is using an `std::string` that is never uninitialized (i.e. code like `int x; return x;` is undefined behavior, `std::string s; return s;` is instead ok).

Answer (score 3):

Using a function:

```
int inputdata()
{
    int data;
    std::cin >> data;
    return data;
}
```

Then:

```
int a=inputdata();
```

For data itself:

```
int inputdata()
{
    static bool isDataDeclared=false;
    if (isDataDeclared==true)
    {
    goto read_data;
    }
    else
    {
        isDataDeclared=true;
    }
    static int data=inputdata();
    return data;
    read_data:
    std::cin >> data;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: But now do it to `data` too!

Comment: @JosephMansfield I think, in the original question, sometimes you just want to initialize a variable to a user-input value as opposed to a system default, an undefined value or your own value which you refuse to define. For the purposes of `data` though, I feel there is no need to "do the same" to it, since it will only exist in the function's local scope for all of three lines of execution time, and perhaps if the function is marked as inline it may even be optimized away altogether. `int old = inputdata();` may end up as equivalent to `int old; std::cin >> old;` if that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not for `int`, but for your own types:

```
class MyType {
    int value;
public:
    MyType(istream& is) {
        is >> *this;
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, MyType& object);
};  

istream& operator>>(istream& is, MyType& object) {
    return is >> object.value;
}
```

Then you can create the type with the `istream` passed to the constructor:

```
int main() {
    istringstream iss("42");
    MyType object(iss);
}
```