# Why is one of these examples undefined behavior and the other is not?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

A comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14914814/2725810) reply states that the following code should not be used because it exhibits undefined behavior:

```
int old = (std::cin >> old, old);
```

A similar code was also greatly scorned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842945/2725810), in particular for exhibiting undefined behavior.

On the other hand, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615656/2725810) highly up-voted reply suggests the following code as an example of usefulness of the comma operator:

```
while (cin >> str, str != "STOP") {
    //process str
}
```

I assume that this code would not be up-voted if it exhibited undefined behavior.

**The question**: if the first code is undefined behavior (presumably because of using the result of reading from `cin` without checking the status of the latter), then why is the second code fine?

**EDIT:** The question is answered in the comment section for the first example. What the second example does not show is that `str` is an instance of `std::string` and so is initialized. Therefore, there is no undefined behavior.

Comment: It seems @6502 already answered you in comment section of other question?

Comment: Note the first comment to that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator/1615656#comment1484373_1615656

Comment: This also depends a lot on the C++ standard used to build the application. See e.g. [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378989/why-does-stringstream-change-value-of-target-on-failure).

Comment: Lots of myths popping up regarding this question - yes there's probably a good duplicate out there somewhere, but I thought it worthwhile submitting a short "wrap-up" answer.

Comment: The first question you link to has no answers so there is no basis for claiming that the code has undefined behaviour. Comments do not serve as answers.

Answer (score 5):

The statement `int old = (std::cin >> old, old);` is well-defined since C++11 **assuming that non-whitespace characters are read**. This is because `old` is set to zero if `std::cin` fails in such a case. The use of the *expression separator* operator `,` is also legitimate as it sequences the expressions `std::cin >> old` and `old`. If no non-whitespace characters are countered then `old` is still not changed by `std::cin >> old` and the behaviour of the code is undefined.

Assuming `str` is a `std::string` type, `(cin >> str, str != "STOP")` is always 
well-defined. If `cin >> str` fails then initial (perhaps default-constructed) value of `str` is retained, and again `,` sequences the expressions.

Comment: "old is set to zero if std::cin fails. " is not correct.  It is set to zero if non-whitespace characters are read but cannot be converted to int.  It is left unchanged if no non-whitespace characters could be extracted.

Comment: "extraction" does not begin until the sentry object has completed successfully. See from your page "1-4) Behaves as a FormattedInputFunction. **After constructing and checking the sentry object**, which may skip leading whitespace, **extracts** an integer value by calling std::num_get::get()".  You can check the standard (istream.formatted) as a more detailed and authoritative reference.

Comment: @M.M I'll review later. Gotta shoot off to a meeting now.

Answer (score 2):

Both answers are bad answers but only first one may exhibit undefined behavior.

> ```
> int old = (std::cin >> old, old);
> ```

When `std::cin >> old` fails then `old` can have its value that it had. So it can remain as uninitialized `int` and so reading from it is undefined behavior.

> ```
> while (cin >> str, str != "STOP") {
>     //process str
> }
> ```

When `cin >> str` fails then `str` has its previous value. Assuming `str` is `std::string` it can not have had uninitialized state unlike aggregate types. So it will have its previous value for example default-constructed value `""` or previously read value `"MOP"`. Reading from it and comparing with `"STOP"` is never undefined behavior. However it is very likely that `cin >> str` will fail next cycle again and so str will never be `"STOP"` and so it will be endless loop and so [`&&` is likely better than comma there](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b79476e2effe39a1).

Also it is worth to note that we [can get real crash](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f67f2e4bd417dcb) when we try to combine first example and second example:

```
std::string old = (std::cin >> old, old);
```

When streams are not set to throw on failures then we should check state of those manually (and `std::cin` is not special) since those may end and fail. Unfortunately lot of tutorial examples do not do it. Therefore some people seem to think that the stream operations are suitable for inserting into middle of some expression using comma operator.

**Edit:**

I am unsure about comment that it is different from C++11. Did dig, but couldn't find confirmation in standard. Trying this code with g++ did not read zero on case of error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream in("42");

    int i = 0;
    std::cout << i << '\n'; // outputs 0
    in >> i;
    std::cout << i << '\n'; // outputs 42
    i = 666;
    in >> i;
    std::cout << i << '\n'; // outputs 666 
    // so it did leave value of i like it was 
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/469b941d2e6f5ce5). Also [std::cin does not seem special](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc85f57e5e4ba8db) in any way. Of course it may be that the implementation of g++ is incorrect or that the failed input is required to set the `i` only on case of subset of failures and so the first example still may exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Since C++11 the first example will not be UB since `old` will be initialized even if the input operation failed. See [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379073/440558) of mine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is not mentioned in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator>>/. Could you please reply with a quote from the standard?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning To be honest, cplusplus.com isn't a very good reference site, as they are not always fully updated and in the past have actually been wrong. In my answer I have links to cppreference.com which is very up to date and follows the standard very closely. I don't really have the time to find the relevant sections in the standard, but the drafts are available freely (see e.g. [here for links](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I made experiment and seems that failed input does not modify value at least with g++ 9.2.0.