# How to manage memory management in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

i need clarification for memory management concepts.

i declare one variable in .h

```
    @interface RootViewController : UIViewController
    {
         NSMutableArray *objMutableArray;
    }
    @property (nonatomic,retain)   NSMutableArray *objMutableArray;
```

in .m file

```
    @implementation RootViewController

    @synthesize objMutableArray=_objMutableArray;

    - (void)viewDidload
    {
         [super viewDidload];

         self.objMutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        [self.objMutableArray addObject:@"FirstRow"];
        [self.objMutableArray addObject:@"SecondRow"];
        [self.objMutableArray addObject:@"ThirdRow"];
        [self.objMutableArray addObject:@"FourthRow"];
        [self.objMutableArray addObject:@"FifthRow"];
    }
```

i used self.objMutableArray all places. but when i release memory for that instance i used _objMutableArray.

```
    - (void)dealloc
    {
         [_objMutableArray release];
         [super dealloc];
    }
```

actually i confused when i release memory for that instance. please tell me i did correct or i must release "objMutableArray" object.

Comment: Meta-meta-meta? Memory management management? Or do you only want to ask "how to manage memory"?

Comment: i need clarification in above situation, which object memory will release in deallocation

Comment: @PartiallyFinite Let him use whichever technology he wants to use. You see, he wants to understand manual memory management. **Be glad that a beginner wants to understand manual memory management.**

Comment: @PartiallyFinite Exactly. Even better, one should learn C first and only then should one continue with Objective-C and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using manual memory management and not ARC. Which is fine, but you got it wrong.

> please tell me i did correct or i must release "objMutableArray" object.

Of course you have to release it because you created it using `alloc`. But how you did it is not correct. You are leaking memory because in the `viewDidUnload` method (I suppose that should be `viewDidLoad` instead, shouldn't it!?) you are assigning to a `retain` property - your object will have a reference count of two (one because of `+ alloc`, one because of `(retain)`).

Now when you are releasing it in `- dealloc`, it will still have a reference count of one, so your class doesn't dispose of its ownership, hence the memory leak.

**Solution:**

You can use either the property or the instance variable. Don't mix the two. Approach #1:

```
_objMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// ...

[_objMutableArray release];
```

Approach #2:

```
self.objMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

// ...

self.objMutableArray = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code

### 1) Did you mean viewDidLoad instead of viewDidUnload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     self.objMutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     ......
     ......

}
```

### 2) You don't need to alloc/init since you are retaining the array

Use

```
self.objMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

instead of

```
self.objMutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

### 3) Now your actual question, When releasing in dealloc

I think this question is [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107440/how-to-use-dealloc-when-dealing-with-auto-synthesized-properties).

Comment: thank you krishna, my actual question is when i write synthesize for  objMutableArray object, i declared _ objMutableArray. and i used self. objMutableArray. now which object memory i should release

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this `viewDidUnload` be `viewDidLoad`. Since you have written `@synthesize objMutableArray=_objMutableArray;`, so from there on if you want to access this property directly without making use of setters and getters. You will have to use `_objMutableArray`. That line in dealloc `[_objMutableArray release];` will decrease the objects retain count by one, such that if the resultant retain count is 0, the the object will be released.