# C: explain if(exit(0),0){} line of code

Tags: c, exit

I am learning C and as an exercise, I'm trying to write a simple program without any semicolons. I've had some trouble with replacing `return 0` statement but I've found that this is (the only?) way to do it in C: `if(exit(0),0){}`.

How exactly does this statement work?

I know that `exit()` from `stdlib` is a void function but I don't understand what the `,0` part in the `if` works (the rest is clear to me).

Comment: outside `main` function they are not equivalent.

Comment: @ouah I believe outside main also `if(exit(0),0) == f(0)` Am I wrong. What is your point **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan My point is that `return 0` returns from a function while `exit(0)` exits from program: this is not the same operation.

Comment: @ouah ahaa :) silly question. yes true, got it..

Comment: `return` is a statement, so it can't be used without a semi-colon. A function is an expression, so none is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `,` operator in C evaluates both its arguments, and returns the value of the second one.  So the expression

```
exit(0), 0
```

calls `exit(0)` and returns 0. So the code you posted is effectively equivalent to:

```
exit(0);
if (0) {}
```

However, `exit()` should terminate the process, so this should never actually return. The idiom is just being used to prevent spurious compiler warnings.

Comment: The comma operator is one of the few where the order of evaluation of the operands is specified. There's a sequence point after the evaluation of the first argument, even.

Comment: `,` evaluates its operands in a *specified* order: first left, then right.

Comment: `exit(0),0` does not *return* 0.  It evaluates to 0.  Perhaps semantic niggling, but there is no return here.

Comment: It's not just to "prevent warnings" but to avoid a constraint violation. Since `exit` has return type `void`, it cannot be used as the controlling expression for an `if` statement. The `,0` has nothing to do with the *value* of the expression, which won't be used anyway. It's to give the expression the right *type*.

Comment: @R.. The code I said it's equivalent to doesn't have `exit(0)` as the condition expression of the `if`, it's before the `if`.

Answer (score 5):

While learning C, there is no value to figuring out how to write a program without semi-colons. Sounds like you've deviated from learning C into playing with useless tricks.

To answer your question though, when you have multiple statements separated by commas, the "result" is the final statement. `if` needs some statement with a value to evaluate, and since `exit()` is void it has no value. the 0 following that comma provides a value for `if`.

Comment: I haven't deviated - just making a break from K&R's exercises.

Answer (score 2):

When you writes

```
int i = (5, 7);
```

`i` **assigned** `7` **not** `5`

In parenthesis `,` separated expressions executes from LHS to RHS.

Similarly `if(exit(0), 0) == if(0)` , but **exit(0) executes first**. (*not optimize to blank*)

My following example and its output will help you upto some extent to understand its behavior:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(char* c){
 printf("%s\n", c);
 return 0;
}
int main(){
 int i = (fun("1"),fun("2"));
 if(fun("3"),7){
   printf("ONE %d", i);
 }
 else{
  printf("TWO %d", i);
 }
}
```

its Output:

```
1
2
3
ONE 0
```

*Notice* specially last of output **`ONE`** 0 printed  because in `if(fun("3"),7) == if(7)`. Otherwise `fun()` returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the **[comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)**.

It means that the right value of the operator is returned, and the left part is evaluated.

In this case it is used so the `exit()` can be put in the `if` statement, and the 0 is passed as parameter to be checked in the `if` statement (it can't work on a void value).

Comment: Would be interesting to have a coma operator.

Comment: A bottle of vodka should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Comma operator may be treated as a give same effect as`;` in normal programming. Actually in this case every expression inside `if` will be evaluated. But whenever `exit()` is called the program will terminate. For details about comma operatorFollow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator)