# Bizarre condition syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, for-loop, conditional-statements

I came across the following `for` loop with a very unusual condition

```
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < ( 10, 20 ) ; i++ ) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

This source code compiled successfully. It executed the loop with `i` with values from 0 to 19 (the `10` in the expression `(10, 20)` seems to have no effect on the number of iterations).

My question:
What is this condition syntax? Why doesn't it cause a compile error?

**EDIT:**
The bigger picture: this questions started with a bug, the original condition was supposed to be `i < std::min( <expr A>, <expr B> )` and for some reason I omitted the `std::min`.

So, I was wondering why the code compiled in the first place. Now I see the bug is a legit (albeit useless) syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: A better question would be "what is the point of 10?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the `comma operator`. It evaluates both sides of the expression, and returns the right one.

So, expression `(10, 20)` does nothing, but returns '20'.

See also

- [Uses of C comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator).
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 3):

`(10, 20)` means evaluate the integer 10, then evaluate 20, then return 20 (the rightmost). So it just means 20.

The comma operator is often useful in `for` loops, as it allows things such as `x = 0, y = 1` (i.e. two assignments in one expression), but here it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

`,` operator in c++ work as a binary operator which checks first value, discard it and return the next value. In short.

`for(int i=0;i<(10,20);i++)` will be equal to `for(int i=0;i<20;i++)`