# comma separated arguments in if statement condition

Tags: c, if-statement

Whats the significance of first argument in an `if` statement if it's just going to be ignored?  For instance, in:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  if(1,0)
    printf("abc");
  else
    printf("qwe");
}
```

Comment: No significance at all. May be the programmer did that to make the if condition false.

Comment: This thread gives some explanation on the subject. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/22745/

Comment: Also, I believe this is a duplicate of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not an argument list, it's the comma operator.

If you have a statement like `foo(), bar()`, then `foo()` will be called and its result discarded, then `bar()` will be called and the entire statement's result will be `bar()`'s result. Something like `if(foo(),bar())` might be used if calling `foo()` has some side effect that needs to happen for some reason.

For something like `1,0`, that is exactly the same as just saying `0` and there is no significance to the `1`.