# Odd variable assignment

Tags: c++, syntax, variable-assignment

Good day, everyone.

I've come across a peculiar piece of code today, which I don't quite understand.
I don't even know how to search for this particular problem.

In this code, which works, a variable assignment is done like this:

```
if(condition) {
    Var1 = false, Var2 = false;
}
```

Now, I was under the impression, that ALL commands need to be terminated by a semicolon instead of a comma. I am familiar with the syntax

```
Var1 = Var2 = false;
```

but not with the one posted above. The compiler (g++) doesn't even throw me a warning or anything...am I missing something from the specification here?
Or is the compiler generous with me and just replaces the `,` with a `;` internally? If so, shouldn't he at least throw a warning?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Ah, thank you very much. I was at an absolute loss as to what to search for. I'll check that link right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I missing something from the specification here?

Yes, it's the "comma operator", specified by C++11 5.18. It evaluates the sub-expression to the left, then the one to the right, and the overall result is that of the right-hand one.

In this case, it's equivalent to two expression statements separated by `;`

It's useful in places like `if/while/for` where you're only allowed one expression, but might want to do more than one thing:

```
while (++i, --j != 0)
```

and also if you like to jam multiple statements together to make life difficult for whoever has to read your code.

Comment: Hmm, this one's interesting. I may be able to use it in the future. You learn something new every day. Thank you. :)

Comment: @ATaylor You don't want to use it (except maybe for obfuscation).  Mike made that quite clear.  There are very few, if any valid uses of the comma operator.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, I came to the same conclusion by myself. Still, thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type). ([read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator))

Answer (score 1):

As Alexandru Barbarosie pointed out, there's quite a thorough explanation on what's happening at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator

To quickly summarize it for whomever stumbles across this post: When used outside of for loops and stuff, the `,` actually has the same effect as the `;`.

For more information, please visit the link.