# A special and strange usage of () in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, operators

I found a usage of () in this code

```
    int a, b, c;
    int x = (a= 2,b=5, a+b,++b );
    cout<<x;
```

I can't find any exmaple in Microsoft Docs or other place.
Have anyone tell me What is the role of ()?

Comment: Look at the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)

Comment: It's the same as for *any* expression. The important part is the use of the *comma expression* inside the parentheses.

Comment: Very similar to [return list of values between parenthesis \(10, 20, 30, 40)/?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20001349/1708801)

Comment: The upshot is that each of the comma statements will be performed and x will be assigned the value from the last one. The third one `a+b` seems dubious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just `()` around an expression.

The expression uses `operator,`.  `operator,` takes the left hand argument, evaluates, it, discards it, then evaluates and returns the right hand argument.  (Unless, of course, you overload it)