# Why is the output of following C code 10? What I mean is why is printf giving x as output?

Tags: c

**Compiled using GCC on a Fedora 20 Desktop, the following code outputs 10.**

```
int x=10;
int y=5;
printf("%d",(y,x));
```

Comment: comma operator evaluates to last value

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Another _newbie_ question this.

Comment: Hi guys it is true I am new here. So if anyone of you can show me how things work, it will be great help.

Comment: @AnudeepSamaiya Most of the rules for writing good bug reports apply here, even though you are not reporting a bug. For instance, you said that you found the behavior of printing `10` strange, but you do not say why or what you expected. Considering that printing `10` is the correct behavior, that makes your question difficult to answer. Then, you invite people to post a random list of “puzzlers”. This is not how this site works. A stackoverflow answer is a solution to a programming problem that you face. Questions are not polls. It is all explained in http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, `(y,x)` means evaluating `x` and `y` and returning only `x`. EG. From wikipedia:

> the comma operator (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

Answer (score 2):

That´s the "comma operator" (not to be confused
with the comma when separating function parameters.)

The "result" is only the last part, but if the other parts are functions etc.,
they will be executed too.

Answer (score 1):

In C    `(exp1,exp2)`

First `exp1` is evaluated, then `exp2` is evaluated, and the value of `exp2` is returned for the whole expression.

1. `(exp1, exp2)` is like `(exp1 && exp2)` but both `exp1` and `exp2` will
   always be evaluated, whatever `exp1` returns.
2. `(exp1, exp2)` is like `{ exp1; exp2; }` but it can be used as an
   expression in a function call or assignment.