# Syntax to call a member function before constructor member initialization

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, initialization

I have seen something like the following code used to call a member function before the constructor is called. The constructor initialization for _data calls member function 'function()' before the constructor.

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
private:
    int *_data;
    void function();
};

foo::foo() :
    _data((int *)(function(), NULL))
{
    std::cout << "foo::constructor called" << std::endl;
}

void foo::function()
{
    std::cout << "foo::function called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo * _foo = new foo;
    delete _foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo::function called
foo::constructor called
```

I don't really understand the syntax for the _data constructor initialization. If you do the following:

```
foo::foo() :
  _data((int *)function())
```

you get a type cast error:
C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'int *'

Could anyone explain the what is going on here?

```
foo::foo() :
  _data((int *)(function(), NULL))
```

Comment: `function()` returns `void`. And yeah, you can't convert `void` to a non-`void` type because it doesn't make sense. This code uses the comma operator to first call the function, then throw away its void return value, yield `NULL` and assign that to `_data` member function.

Comment: please don't do this, if you need complex construction please consider a static factory function. The benefits are far outweighed by the undefined behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

> ... a binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type).

So `(int *)(function(), NULL)` first calls `function()` and then returns `NULL`.

The `NULL` is then cast to `int*` and used to initialize `_data`.

Comment: Addition: As an aside, be aware that the object is still indeterminate, so reading any of it's values (you don't) would be inadvisable.

Comment: where could sth like this be useful?

Comment: @MartinMeeser See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator) and the duplicate there.

Answer (score 0):

This construct uses the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) to achieve its effect.

When evaluating `(function(), NULL)` it first evaluates `function`, then `NULL`. The overall result of the expression is `NULL`, which is then casted to `int *`. Hence, `_data` is initialised to `NULL`.