# code for finding 10001th prime is not running

Tags: c++

I am using this following code to find 10001th prime number but it is not running.
I am using devc++, but when I run this code, a blank screen comes up.

This is my Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int prime(int a)
{
    int p=0;
    for(int j=2;j<=a/2,p<=0;j++)
    {
        if(a%j==0)
        {
            p++;
        }
    }
    if(p==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    return 0;
}

int main()    
{
    int i,c=0;
    for(i=2;c<=10001;i++)
    {
        if(prime(1))
        {
            c++;
        }
    }
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need `if(prime(i))` instead of `if(prime(1))`

Comment: Also, comma does not mean "and".

Comment: I don't think so, @ArunA.S. `i` is the tested number while `c` is the counter for found primes. Using a while-loop would have made that clearer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**point 1:**
you are passing `if(prime(1))` argument `1` every time change this line to

```
if(prime(i))
```

**point 2:**
Change this line

```
for(int j=2;j<=a/2,p<=0;j++)
```

To

```
for(int j=2;(j<=a/2 && p<=0);j++)
```

**Point 3:**
Change this line

```
cout<<i;
```

To

```
cout<<i-1;  // as at the end of `for` loop it will increment to `1` so print `i-1`.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I think you meant

```
if(prime(i))
```

instead of 
    `if(prime(1))`

Secondly, there are many gaps in this code .. First, you can verify if the number a divides by j with j taking a maximum value of sqrt(a) (using math.h library) , it would be faster when working with higher values.
Another thing, you said this is a code for finding the 10001th prime number not the number of prime numbers until 10001 and `cout<<i;` in the end doesn't make any sense, I think you meant `cout<<c;`

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at each problem.

**First**, you need to use

```
if( prime(i) )
```

instead of

```
if( prime(1) )
```

I believe that was a typo on your part.

**Second**, as `i` is incremented after the for loop, you need to change

```
cout << i;
```

to

```
cout << i-1;
```

**Third**, the comma operator only executes the expression at the end. What you need here is `&&`. So change

```
for(int j = 2 ; j <= a/2 , p <= 0 ; j++)
```

to

```
for(int j = 2 ; j <= a/2 && p <= 0 ; j++ )
```

For more info on the comma operator, see [Uses of C comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator)

**Lastly**, change

```
for( i = 2 ; c <= 10001 ; i++ )
```

to

```
for( i = 2 ; c < 10001 ; i++ )
```

Otherwise, you will get the 10002th prime number.

These should fix your problem.