# How is the return type of a ternary operator determined?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, operator-precedence

I was solving a problem about movement of a bishop on a chessboard. At one point of my code, I had the following statement:

```cpp
std::cout << (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2 << std::endl;
```

This generates the following error:

> ```
> error: invalid operands of types 'int' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator<<'
> ```

However, I instantaneously fixed this error by including an additional variable in my code:

```cpp
int steps = (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2;
std::cout << steps << std::endl;
```

How does the ternary operator work, and how is its return type determined (as the compiler called it `<unresolved overloaded function type>`)?

Comment: I think the ternary operator has precedence over the << operator. And so the first branch of the ternary was 1, and the other 2 << std;:endl

Comment: Look at operator precedence. << is higher than == and ?? (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: This also fixes the error: `std::cout << ((abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2) << std::endl;`.  No need for an intermediate variable.

Comment: Here is an [interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300738/why-ternary-operator-does-not-support-blocks) I found searching through this site before asking here.

Comment: This problem is caused by the repurposing of the shift operator - `int x = whatever ? 1 << 2 : 1 << 3;` has the "obvious" meaning.

Comment: @Neo: Just to set the record straight, seeing as your upvoted comment has gained a little more visibility now that the question's got into HNQ – the fact that the third argument ended up being `2 << std::endl` rather than `2` means the `<<` operator has precedence *over the ternary operator*, not the other way round. I'm sure that's what you meant to say but for some reason ended up saying the opposite.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This has nothing to do with how the return type is deduced and everything to do with [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  When you have

```
std::cout << (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2 << std::endl;
```

it isn't

```
std::cout << ((abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2) << std::endl;
```

because `?:` has lower precedence than `<<`.  That means what you actually have is

```
(std::cout << (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1))) ? 1 : (2 << std::endl);
```

and this is why you get an error about an `<unresolved overloaded function type>`.  Just use parentheses like

```
std::cout << ((abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2) << std::endl;
```

and you'll be okay.

Comment: So my guess is: the compiler tried to binary this part `1 : 2 << std::endl` and failed.

Comment: @MerajalMaksud Yes.  Basically the two things it would return became `1` and `(2 << std::endl)`

Comment: @MerajalMaksud Almost, but not quite. It tried to compile `2 << std::endl` and failed.

Comment: As a fun fact, `std::cout << 2 - (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) << std::endl;` is equivalent to the fixed code.

Comment: The original code is actually parsed as `(std::cout << (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1))) ? 1 : (2 << std::endl);` "Fortunately", iostreams can be converted to boolean expressions, i.e., the first part will not cause errors (just unexpected behavior).

Answer (score 12):

You have to put parentheses around a ternary operation:

```
std::cout << ((abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2) << std::endl;
```

If not the the `<<` operator goes to the `2` and it gives an error because it doesn't have such overloaded function.

This happens because the bitwise left shift operator (`<<`) has a higher precedence than the ternary operator. You can see the full list of operators and their precedence in [this page of the C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 8):

Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), that line is treated as:

```
(std::cout << (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1))) ? 1 : (2 << std::endl);
```

Change it to

```
std::cout << ((abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2) << std::endl;
//           ^----------------------------------^
//           Surrounding parentheses
```

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to see the mistake when the parsing order is visualized:

```
std::cout << (abs(c2-c1) == abs(r2-r1)) ? 1 : 2 << std::endl;
\_______/                                                      <--- #1
             \________________________/   V   \~~~~error~~~/   <--- #2
             \_____________________________________________/   <--- #3
\__________________________________________________________/   <--- #4
\___________________________________________________________/  <--- #5
```

Answer (score 4):

The literal answer to the question you asked is the algorithm in the [[expr.cond] secton of the C++ language standard.](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#section.8.16)

The basic rule “determined whether an implicit conversion sequence can be formed from the second operand to the target type determined for the third operand, and vice versa.”  If there isn’t one possible conversion, or there is more than one, it’s a syntax error, but there are several special cases (which don’t apply here):

- If both are arithmetic or `enum` types, you get the same kind of implicit conversion for `p ? a : b` that determines the type of an expression such as `a + b` or `a * b`.
- One of the targets may be a `throw` expression, and is treated as having the type of the other.
- If one of the targets is a bitfield, so is the type of the conditional expression
- Pointers with different qualifiers (such as `const` and `volatile`) have their qualifiers unified.

The result is a glvalue if the targets are glvalues of the same type, and a prvalue otherwise.

When in doubt, you can always explicitly cast one or both of the operands so that they have the same type.

Your actual problem here is operator precedence, as the accepted answer explains.  That is, the compiler parses the third operand as `2 << std::endl`, rather than 2.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

> When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row of the table above with a precedence will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it with a lower precedence. For example, the expressions `std::cout << a & b` and `*p++` are parsed as `(std::cout << a) & b` and `*(p++)`, and not as `std::cout << (a & b)` or `(*p)++`.
>
> Operators that have the same precedence are bound to their arguments in the direction of their associativity. For example, the expression `a = b = c` is parsed as `a = (b = c)`, and not as `(a = b) = c` because of right-to-left associativity of assignment, but `a + b - c` is parsed `(a + b) - c` and not `a + (b - c)` because of left-to-right associativity of addition and subtraction.
>
> Associativity specification is redundant for unary operators and is only shown for completeness: unary prefix operators always associate right-to-left (`delete ++*p` is `delete (++(*p)))` and unary postfix operators always associate left-to-right (`a[1][2]++` is `((a[1])[2])++`). Note that the associativity is meaningful for member access operators, even though they are grouped with unary postfix operators: `a.b++` is parsed `(a.b)++` and not `a.(b++)`.
>
> Operator precedence is unaffected by operator overloading. For example, `std::cout << a ? b : c;` parses as `(std::cout << a) ? b : c;` because the precedence of arithmetic left shift is higher than the conditional operator.