# Can I substitue C++ ternary operator for if in this case?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following block:

```
int i = 0;
std::apply([&](auto &&... args) mutable {
    ((ef = (i++ == id) ?
           args.modifyEffectVec(ef, arr) : ef), ...);
}, EffectsTuple);
```

When `i++==id`, this is executed: `args.modifyEffectVec(ef, arr)`. I want to log when this happens, so I know for which `i` it happened. I tried

```
int i = 0;
std::apply([&](auto &&... args) mutable {
    ((ef = (i++ == id) ?
           {
            ALOGV(TAG, "modifying effect for id %d", id);
            args.modifyEffectVec(ef, arr);
           } : ef), ...);
}, EffectsTuple);
```

but I discovered [Why ternary operator does not support blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300738/why-ternary-operator-does-not-support-blocks)

I'm not sure how can I substitute this ternary for an if because it happens inside this thing called a fold expression

Comment: Instead of making it a block, why not just put the thing into its own lambda and call that? It can do the logging call and execute the piece of code.

Comment: Extremely hairy, but I think that the comma operator would work here: `/* cond */ ? (ALOGV(TAG, "modifying effect for id %d", id), args.modifyEffectVec(ef, arr)) : ...`. That said, the code is already hairy, and I think it would be much easier to read if the `std::apply(...)` was extracted out into a new function.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just replace `;` with `,`?

```
int i = 0;
std::apply([&](auto &&... args) mutable {
    ((ef = (i++ == id) ?
            ALOGV(TAG, "modifying effect for id %d", id),
            args.modifyEffectVec(ef, arr);
            : ef), ...);
}, EffectsTuple);
```

EDIT:

The "," is a comma operator which adds a sequence point between the statements, that way you avoid putting a block there and both statements will still run.

More can be read here [Comma_operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained the difference between them, and why one works when the other does not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes that is true, I forgot that it was a bit obscure :)

Answer (score 1):

There is *one* family of expressions in C++ that allow for embedding an arbitrary number of statements within them. It's lambda expression. So if you want to execute a couple of statements in your fold, you can always wrap them in a lambda, and immediately invoke it over the fold.

```
int i = 0;
std::apply([&](auto &&... args) {
    ([&](auto &&) { 
         if (ef = (i++ == id)) {
            ALOGV(TAG, "modifying effect for id %d", id);
            args.modifyEffectVec(ef, arr);
         }
     } (std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)), ...);
}, EffectsTuple);
```

You don't seem to be *using* `args` in your fold, but in case you are, the extra lambda is written to forward it on correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, as you only call the function for `id`th tuple argument, you might do

```
std::apply([&](auto &&... args) mutable {
    auto funcs[] = {std::function{[&](){ args.modifyEffectVec(ef, arr);}...};
    ALOGV(TAG, "modifying effect for id %d", id),

    funcs[id]();
}, EffectsTuple);
```