# How this if-else condition can be replaced by ternary operator

Tags: c

Please help me to rewrite the below condition in a better way

This is a c code

```
 if(a == MACRO1)
 strcpy(x,"S")
else if (a == MACRO2)
 strcpy(x,"K");
```

Comment: I probably would not use a ternary expression here, because there is no final else condition in your logic.  I like your code the way it is now.

Comment: What makes you think using the ternary operator would be better here?

Comment: BTW strcpy for one character seems quite overkill; woule really need to see the while code sample

Comment: Since you are comparing for equality with two distinct values, rather than equality with one value and a general "else" case, the ternary operator isn't a good fit for this operation.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(a == MACRO1)
 strcpy(x,"S")
else 
 strcpy(x,"K");
```

can be :

```
strcpy(x, (a == MACRO1) ? "S" : "K");
```

but

```
if(a == MACRO1)
 strcpy(x,"S")
else if (a == MACRO2)
 strcpy(x,"K");
```

has a missing else and to do

```
strcpy(x, (a == MACRO1) ? "S" : ((a == MACRO2) ? "K" : x));
```

is **not** correct because the argument of *strcpy*  must  not overlap but in that specific case not sure it is a true problem (even undefined behavior) , but also *x* is may be not yet initialized, and what about the performances ...

Comment: With `char *strcpy(char * restrict s1,
const char * restrict s2);`, arguments referenced data of `strcpy` must not overlap is true, else technical UB per 6.7.3.1  4, although I agree: doubtful true problem with `strcpy(x, x);`

Answer (score 4):

Formally, it can be rewritten as equivalent

```
a == MACRO1 ? strcpy(x, "S") : 
a == MACRO2 ? strcpy(x, "K") : 0;
```

but there's no meaningful reason to do so, unless it is just a puzzle (or unless there's a credible reason to [maintain expression semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613230/uses-of-c-comma-operator/1618867#1618867)).

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside this [beautiful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443105/how-this-if-else-condition-can-be-replaced-by-ternary-operator/54443661#54443661), this cannot be written as a two "nested" ternary conditional operators since there is nothing to do for any value of `a` other than `MACRO1` and `MACRO2`, and it's not possible to trick `strcpy` into a no-op. (The behaviour of copying `x` to itself is *undefined*.)

So you are best off leaving the code as it is. Note that in terms of programming history, the ternary conditional operator was invented before the `if` `else` control block due perhaps to the deficiencies in the former, as epitomised in the case you present.

You could submit

```
strnpcy(x, a == MACRO1 ? "S" : "K", 2 * (a == MACRO1 + a == MACRO2));
```

to the next obfuscation contest though.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy( x, (a == MACRO1)? "S" :
           (a == MACRO2)? "K" : "error" );
```

Like your original code, this will copy either `"S"` or `"K"` to variable `x`.

If `a` is ***neither*** `MACRO1` nor `MACRO2`, it will copy `"error"` to buffer `x` with an assumption that `x` is large enough to hold `"error"` string.
*(You should figure out a better way to handle the case where `a` is neither of the two macros)*

Answer (score -1):

it can be also

```
{
    char *dummy;

    dummy = a == MACRO1 ? strcpy(x, "TextA") : a == MACRO2 ? strcpy(x, "TextB") : strcpy(x, "error");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way, behaving like original, appending nothing if a doesn't match either MACRO1 or MACRO2:

```
strcpy(x, (a == MACRO1)?"S":(a == MACRO2)?"K":x);
```

Comment: This isn't like the original; it overwrites `x` with the empty string if neither comparison  succeeds. You could replace `""` with `x`, which would at least make it an expense no-op (or actually undefined, as pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54443256/1126841).

Comment: (If `strcat` were used instead of `strcpy`, then `""` could be used as the identity element for an expensive no-op.)

Comment: Fixed! Thanks, I have overlooked it and at first I thought it was strcat, not strcpy :D